# Image Text Wrapping in Markdown with Gatsby Transform Remark

Tags: image, markdown, gatsby, word-wrap

I'm trying to figure out a solution to wrap text around images within a markdown document using Gatsby. I have tried the `wrapperStyle` option but not entirely sure how to get it to work. I've seen on Gatsby's website using the following code:

```
wrapperStyle: fluidResult => `flex:${_.round(fluidResult.aspectRatio, 2)};`,
```

But I am very novice to coding and am unsure how to read this (I'm a technical writer by trade). Also, adding this makes my images disappear when I build the repo.

Here is a condensed snippet from my gatsby-config.js file in case someone is unsure of where I'm talking about in gatsby-config.js.

```js
      resolve: `gatsby-transformer-remark`,
      options: {
        plugins: [
          {
            resolve: `gatsby-remark-images`,
            options: {
              maxWidth: 800,
            },
```

Comment: What do you mean with "wrap text around images"?

Comment: To have an image float within a body of text and the text can be above, below, and on either side of it.  Or just having a paragraph next to the image would work too.

Comment: How are you printing that image in the layout? Just to know your HTML structure

Comment: @FerranBuireu It's all in markdown so the standard format: `![image name](image location)` and then gatsby formats it.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for `showCaptions` or `markdownCaptions` [option of `gatsby-remark-images`](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/plugins/gatsby-remark-images/#options) plugin. Use it like:

```
{
  resolve: 'gatsby-transformer-remark',
  options: {
    plugins: [
      {
        resolve: 'gatsby-remark-images',
        options: {
          showCaptions: true
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Or customize the element of the caption like:

```
{
  resolve: 'gatsby-remark-images',
    options: {
      showCaptions: ['title', 'alt']
    }
  }
}
```

*Note: with this configuration, if you set the `title`, it will be used as the caption. Otherwise, if you set the `alt` attribute, it will be used instead*

You can find the result of the configuration in this [GitHub thread](https://github.com/gatsbyjs/gatsby/issues/26882):

[image]

Related articles:

- https://medium.com/@sgpropguide/customising-image-display-in-gatsby-3b027d783dce
- https://codeconcisely.com/posts/how-to-add-markdown-image-captions-in-gatsby/

Comment: The main goal is to be able to have paragraphs to the right or left of an image.  Captions do not allow enough flexibility unfortunately.